PyQt6 6.7.0 - How to fix error: No QtMultimedia backends found
Problem on Windows 10 and Windows 11 using Anaconda.
Here is the full error message for PyQt6=6.7.0:
No QtMultimedia backends found. Only QMediaDevices, QAudioDevice, QSoundEffect, QAudioSink, and QAudioSource are available.
Failed to initialize QMediaPlayer "Not available"
Failed to create QVideoSink "Not available"

Installed PyQt6 using a requirements file:
PyQt6
PyQt6-WebEngine
requests
pyserial
pynput

Here are a couple things I tried:

Reroll version back to PyQt6=6.6.1. This results in an error as well: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtGui: The specified procedure could not be found.
I thought that missing ffmpeg might be the issue so I installed it, but the issue persists.
Tried the setup on Ubuntu (WSL2) and the issue disappears, but there is just a black screen and nothing gets displayed in the widget. (EDIT: Got this up and running, the problem was with differences in file paths in linux vs windows.)

I am new to PyQt so any pointers will be helpful!
Edit: Here is generic code (taken from  here) that gives the same error:
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt6.QtCore import QDir, Qt, QUrl, QSize
from PyQt6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer
from PyQt6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFileDialog, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QStyleFactory,
        QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QSlider, QStyle, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QStatusBar)


class VideoPlayer(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoPlayer, self).__init__(parent)

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer()

        btnSize = QSize(16, 16)
        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()

        openButton = QPushButton("Open Video")   
        openButton.setToolTip("Open Video File")
        openButton.setStatusTip("Open Video File")
        openButton.setFixedHeight(24)
        openButton.setIconSize(btnSize)
        openButton.setFont(QFont("Noto Sans", 8))
        openButton.setIcon(QIcon.fromTheme("document-open", QIcon("D:/_Qt/img/open.png")))
        openButton.clicked.connect(self.abrir)

        self.playButton = QPushButton()
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.playButton.setFixedHeight(24)
        self.playButton.setIconSize(btnSize)
        self.playButton.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.StandardPixmap.SP_MediaPlay))
        self.playButton.clicked.connect(self.play)

        self.positionSlider = QSlider(Qt.Orientation.Horizontal)
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, 0)
        self.positionSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.setPosition)

        self.statusBar = QStatusBar()
        self.statusBar.setFont(QFont("Noto Sans", 7))
        self.statusBar.setFixedHeight(14)

        controlLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        controlLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        controlLayout.addWidget(openButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.playButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.positionSlider)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(videoWidget)
        layout.addLayout(controlLayout)
        layout.addWidget(self.statusBar)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        #help(self.mediaPlayer)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.playbackStateChanged.connect(self.mediaStateChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.durationChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.errorChanged.connect(self.handleError)
        self.statusBar.showMessage("Ready")

    def abrir(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select Media",
                ".", "Video Files (*.mp4 *.flv *.ts *.mts *.avi)")

        if fileName != '':
            self.mediaPlayer.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName))
            self.playButton.setEnabled(True)
            self.statusBar.showMessage(fileName)
            self.play()

    def play(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.playbackState() == QMediaPlayer.PlaybackState.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def mediaStateChanged(self, state):
        if self.mediaPlayer.playbackState() == QMediaPlayer.PlaybackState.PlayingState:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                    self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.StandardPixmap.SP_MediaPause))
        else:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                    self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.StandardPixmap.SP_MediaPlay))

    def positionChanged(self, position):
        self.positionSlider.setValue(position)

    def durationChanged(self, duration):
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, duration)

    def setPosition(self, position):
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(position)

    def handleError(self):
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.statusBar.showMessage("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoPlayer()
    player.setWindowTitle("Player")
    player.resize(900, 600)
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

The videos I want to play are in the same folder as this .py file.
The conda env (python 3.9.2) I am working on has the following packages:
certifi                     2024.6.2
charset-normalizer          3.3.2
idna                        3.7
pip                         24.0
pynput                      1.7.6
PyQt6                       6.7.0
PyQt6-Qt6                   6.7.1
PyQt6-sip                   13.6.0
PyQt6-WebEngine             6.7.0
PyQt6-WebEngine-Qt6         6.7.1
PyQt6-WebEngineSubwheel-Qt6 6.7.1
pyserial                    3.5
requests                    2.31.0
setuptools                  69.5.1
six                         1.16.0
urllib3                     2.2.1
wheel                       0.43.0

PS: MacOS seems to have the same  issue.


You don't need to "reveal code", you have to provide a proper [mre], which reproduces the same issue; 2. How did you install PyQt? 3. What OS? Note that when using the standard Qt distribution, QtMultimedia uses an internal ffmpeg build, but if you're installing it with your OS package management, it can differ.


I am trying to get a video (.mp4) up and running in a widget, but I get that error and a black screen.

I have updated the question to include a minimal reproducible example (at least on my system) @musicamante.

This seems related to the 6.7.0-1 release report. Following messages (in the thread and in the ML) don't mention official fixes, except for a possible workaround that requires local rebuild. A similar, possibly related, PYSIDE-2656 issue was recently found. Remember that it's also important to always report the actual Qt version, which is not always consistent with that of the bindings: for PyQt, use QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR.

I did figure out a workaround. The issue definitely stems from the most recent releases for PyQt6. I will post the answer sometime today. Thanks! @musicamante

The issue with the backend is caused by the new version of PyQt6=6.7.0. Simply rerolling the version of PyQt6 and PyQt6-WebEngine to a previous version was not enough as sub-packages that were installed as a part of this were not rerolled automatically. This caused an issue due to package mismatch:
PyQt6: DLL load failed while importing QtGui: The specified procedure could not be found.

To fix this, reroll all the relevant packages manually. Here is the requirements.txt file I generated after I got it working:
pynput==1.7.7
PyQt6==6.6.0
PyQt6-Qt6==6.6.0
PyQt6-sip==13.6.0
PyQt6-WebEngine==6.6.0
PyQt6-WebEngine-Qt6==6.6.0
PyQt6-WebEngineSubwheel-Qt6==6.7.1
pyserial==3.5
requests==2.32.3

NOTE: I believe the devs are aware of this problem in and have resolved it. It will be released with the next version (check @musicamante's comment as well).

Note: the bug report is about PySide (remember that PySide and PyQt are not the same), and while there may be relations with the two bugs, their fixing may not. According to today's message from the PyQt maintainer, it will be fixed as soon as the next Qt version (6.7.2) is released, which is expected for the end of the next week; if I understand correctly, he will then update PyQt wheels accordingly.

Instead of rolling back, I spent a bunch of time trying to figure out what was missing in the new release so I could actually use it.  You can find the version of ffmpeg that contains the dll's needed at here link the build to download is: ffmpeg-7.0-full_build-shared.  Place (avutil-59.dll
avformat-61.dll
avcodec-61.dll
swresample-5.dll
swscale-8.dll) in the same folder/path as your ffmpeg.exe and that did it for me.

For me the missing dll's were:
avutil-59.dll
avformat-61.dll
avcodec-61.dll
swresample-5.dll
swscale-8.dll

I found them on the gyan build of ffmpeg (link of past builds on git) https://github.com/GyanD/codexffmpeg/releases/tag/7.0, specifically  the ffmpeg-7.0-full_build-shared.zip (or .7z).  In my case the dll with the missing dependencies was ffmpegmediaplugin.dll which in my case was located at:
*user path*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyQt6\Qt6\plugins\multimedia

I just replaced my ffmpeg release and made sure to place the dll's found in the release in the bin folder so they'd be found.

If for some reason you have a later or earlier version of ffmpegmediaplugin.dll because it's associated with a different release of PyQt6, you can discover the missing dll's using a program found here https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies.  After extracting the folder from the download look for the gui version of the program called DependenciesGui.exe ... you can drag and drop the ffmpegmediaplugin.dll right on to the desktop surface/program window and it will find the missing dependencies ... in my case highlighted in red.
